# Mule Filter by IP is not working

Tags: mule, mule-studio

I have a minor issue using Mule IP filter ... As per the Mule documentation http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/34X/Mule+Filter+Processor I have tried to implement 
Here is my following Mule Config :-

```
<filters:config name="Filters" doc:name="Filters"/>
 <flow name="testFlow2" doc:name="testFlow2">
  <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8081" path="filter" doc:name="HTTP"/>
  <filters:filter-by-ip config-ref="Filters" regex="192.168.2.100" doc:name="Filters"/>
  <set-payload value="test data after filter" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
  <logger  level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
 </flow>
```

My IP is `192.168.2.100`  but still it's unable to pass the filter Strangely
But at the same time if I use the following **filter-by-ip-range**  :-

```
<filters:filter-by-ip-range config-ref="Filters"  doc:name="Filters" mask="192.168.2.100" net="255.255.255.0"/>
```

It is able to **`pass`** the filter ...  Please suggest what wrong am I doing ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the address 127.0.0.1 if you are hitting your Service (deployed locally) from your machine.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your reply .. It works .. but what about other IP addresses .. If I want to list IP addresses like the following :- **<filters:filter-by-ip config-ref="Filters" regex="192.168.2.100,192.168.2.101,192.168.2.102" doc:name="Filters"/>** ..then it will not work .. how to handle that case ??..

Comment: The regex you provided for multiple IP addresses also works. Did you test it by firing a request from the 192.168.2.102 machine?

Comment: Yes, I tested with multiple IP addresses

Comment: Did you try firing a request from a different machine than from which the Application is running?